# Derivate of function with parameters

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

I would like to find the extrema of the following function: $f(x)=x^n - n*a*log(x), n=1,2,...$ and $a>0.$ But I have trouble with differentiating and solving for x.

So far, I have:

$f'(x)=n*x^{(n-1)} - (ln x / ln 10) *n*a$

But how can I solve for$ x$ if I set $f'(x)=0.$

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to differentiate the logarithm expression (it looks like you just changed the logarithm to base $e$ but forgot to differentiate). You should have:
$$f'(x)=nx^{n-1}-\frac{d}{dx}\left[na\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(10)}\right]\\=nx^{n-1}-\frac{na}{\ln(10)}\frac{1}{x}$$
Setting this equal to zero, we have:
$$\begin{align}0&=nx^{n-1}-\frac{na}{x\ln(10)}\\\frac{na}{x\ln(10)}&=nx^{n-1}\\\frac{a}{\ln(10)}&=x^n\end{align}$$
Where we know that $n\neq 0$, and implicitly the domain of $f$ requires that $x>0$ since we are using the logarithm function.

Edit: Note that because $a>0$ and of course $\ln(10)>0$, we can take the $n$-th root of both sides, because the left hand side is nonnegative (which is necessary over $\Bbb R$ when $n$ is even). Also, because the domain implicitly requrires $x>0$, we only take the positive solution of the $n$-th root when $n$ is even (and there is only one solution when $n$ is odd).